# error TS2742: The inferred type of 'OrderService' cannot be named without a reference to

Tags: typescript, vite

Today when I use the pnpm to build the project, shows error like this:

```
vite v4.3.9 building for production...
✓ 2781 modules transformed.
dist/style.css             2.63 kB │ gzip:   0.95 kB
dist/rd-component.es.js  452.49 kB │ gzip: 155.89 kB │ map: 1,267.35 kB
No name was provided for external module "react-redux" in "output.globals" – guessing "reactRedux".
No name was provided for external module "redux" in "output.globals" – guessing "redux".
dist/rd-component.umd.js  334.60 kB │ gzip: 140.90 kB │ map: 1,229.84 kB

[vite:dts] Start generate declaration files...
src/service/order/OrderService.ts:5:14 - error TS2742: The inferred type of 'OrderService' cannot be named without a reference to '.pnpm/rdjs-wheel@0.0.7_@babel+core@7.22.1_esbuild@0.17.19_rollup@3.23.1_typescript@5.1.3/node_modules/rdjs-wheel'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.

5 export const OrderService = {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/service/pay/PayService.ts:6:14 - error TS2742: The inferred type of 'PayService' cannot be named without a reference to '.pnpm/rdjs-wheel@0.0.7_@babel+core@7.22.1_esbuild@0.17.19_rollup@3.23.1_typescript@5.1.3/node_modules/rdjs-wheel'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.

6 export const PayService = {
               ~~~~~~~~~~

✓ built in 5.58s
[vite:dts] Declaration files built in 1992ms.
```

this is the pay service defined:

```
import { PayActionType } from '@/action/pay/PayAction';
import { XHRClient } from '@/common/XHRClient';
import { IOrder } from '@/models/pay/IOrder';
import { AnyAction, Store } from 'redux';

export const PayService = {
    doPay:(params: any, store: Store<any, AnyAction>)=>{
        const config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: '/post/alipay/pay/createOrder',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: JSON.stringify(params)
        };
        const actionTypeString: string = PayActionType[PayActionType.CREATE_ORDER];
        return XHRClient.requestWithActionType(config, actionTypeString, store);
    },
    setPayedInfo: (order: IOrder, store: Store<any, AnyAction>) => {
        const actionTypeString: string = PayActionType[PayActionType.SET_PAYED_ORDER_INFO];
        const action = {
            type: actionTypeString,
            data: order
        };
        store.dispatch(action);
    },
    doClearAlipayFormText: (store: Store<any, AnyAction>) => {
        const actionTypeString: string = PayActionType[PayActionType.CLEAR_ALIPAY_FORM_TEXT];
        const action = {
            type: actionTypeString,
            data: ''
        };
        store.dispatch(action);
    }
}

export default PayService;
```

I have tried to delete the `node_modules` and reinstall the dependencies but did not work. what should I do to fixed this issue? this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./typings"
    ],
    "types": [
      "@types/jest"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*",
      ]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "typings/typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "test": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "jsx": "react-jsx"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting "declaration": false in your tsconfig.json fixes the issue.

Comment: could you explain with more detail? why this config work? I remember I already tried to tweak the config but could not work. It is strange becuase it suddenly did not work.

Comment: It is a typescript bug when using pnpm. More detailed: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47663#issuecomment-1519138189

Comment: This didn't fix it for me and seems like a risky change in tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate name in your project can also cause this. For example using `Page` in multiple NextJS route files.